# Shorthand / operator for forEach, map?

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorthand for accessing properties of an array of objects?

```
let o = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3}
];
```

`o.map(item => item.id); // [1, 2, 3]`

Instead with some type of shorthand:

`o[].id; // [1, 2, 3]`

If not, is there a recommendation to add such a thing in the future?

Comment: lodash _.map has this functionality. `_.map(o, 'id');`

Comment: Also with `underscore`, it uses `_.pluck(o, 'id')`

Answer (score 0):

This would pretty much accomplish what i want:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array, 'all', {
    value: function(array) {
        let allProperties = new Set();
        let methods = {};

        array.forEach(o => {
            if(!(o instanceof Object)) return;

            Object.keys(o).forEach(property => {
                allProperties.add(property);
            });
        });

        allProperties.forEach(property => {
            methods[property] = array.map(o => {
                if(!(o instanceof Object)) return o;

                return o[property];
            });
        });

        return methods;
    }
});
```

So that:

```
let o = [
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},
  null,
  {num: 3}
];
```

`Array.all(o).id; // [1, 2, null, undefined]`

It could also extend `Array.prototype` so that `o.all.id` would return the same thing.